# python loop for i in range(n) exceeding specified limit n

Tags: python, for-loop, pdb

I am trying to debug a merge method in a program for merge-sort. Here is the method:

```
def merge(self, leftarray, rightarray):
        n = len(leftarray) + len(rightarray)
        print "len(leftarray) = "+str(len(leftarray))
        print "len(rightarray) = "+str(len(rightarray))
        i = 0
        j = 0
        merged = []

        for k in range(n):
            if i == len(leftarray):
                merged.extend(rightarray[j:])
                k += len(rightarray[j:])

            elif j == len(rightarray):
                merged.extend(leftarray[i:])
                k += len(leftarray[i:])

            elif leftarray[i] <= rightarray[j]:
                merged.append(leftarray[i])
                i += 1

            elif leftarray[i] > rightarray[j] :
                merged.append(rightarray[j])
                j += 1

        return merged
```

The `for k in range(n)` is the loop exhibiting the problem.
Here is the debugger trace:

```
> /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(36)merge()
-> elif j == len(rightarray):
(Pdb) n
> /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(37)merge()
-> merged.extend(leftarray[i:])
(Pdb) n
> /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(39)merge()
-> k += len(leftarray[i:])
(Pdb) n
> /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(30)merge()
-> for k in range(n):
(Pdb) p k
3
(Pdb) n
> /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(31)merge()
-> if i == len(leftarray):
(Pdb) p n
3
(Pdb)
```

As can be seen in the trace, the value of `n` is 3 and execution should not enter the loop when `k` is 3. However execution goes to the line `if i == len(leftarray):` instead of `return merged`.

Comment: `n` steps to the next statement, so you *executed more code* by the time you printed the value of the *variable* `n`.

Comment: a working mergesort http://pastebin.com/E9VSYk7n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python shows you the `for k in range(n)` line **before it executes it**. So `k` is still bound to the result from the last command that touched it:

```
k += len(leftarray[i:])
```

You need to print `k` *after* the `for` loop has assigned the next value in the `range(n)` series to `k`.

To map this out more by annotating your debug steps:

1. ```
   > /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(36)merge()
   -> elif j == len(rightarray):
   ```

   `k` is untouched and still set to what `for k in range(n)` set it to.

   ```
   (Pdb) n
   ```

   You now executed the `j == len(rightarray)` test and it is found to be true so you step to:
2. ```
   > /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(37)merge()
   -> merged.extend(leftarray[i:])
   (Pdb) n
   > /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(39)merge()
   -> k += len(leftarray[i:])
   ```

   `merged` is extended, you stepped to the `k += len(leftarray[i:])` line. `k` is still bound to the value the loop assigned to it.

   ```
   (Pdb) n
   ```

   You now executed `k += len(leftarray[i:])` and `k` is now set to `3`, replacing whatever value it was bound to before.
3. ```
   > /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(30)merge()
   -> for k in range(n):
   ```

   **This line hasn't executed yet**, so `k` is still bound to 3:

   ```
   (Pdb) p k
   3
   (Pdb) n
   ```

   **Now** `k` no longer will be `3`, it'll be the next value in the `range(n)` sequence.
4. ```
   > /home/**/Documents/**/**/merge_sort.py(31)merge()
   -> if i == len(leftarray):
   (Pdb) p n
   3
   ```

   You need to now test `k` again; it'll be 1 or 2, depending on where you were in the iteration process.

The `for` loop determines the iterator *when the loop starts*; you provided it with a `range()` sequence, and it'll follow that sequence you set it. You cannot alter `k` and expect it to not be replaced by the next value from the series.

You'd use a `while` loop to do that instead:

```
k = 0
while k < n:
    # do things, including altering k further
    k += 1
```

Comment: Oh! but now that I executed `p k` while still running the loop the value of `k` is 2. How did it go down from 3?

Comment: @VineetKaushik: you'd use a `while` loop. Python `for` is a *foreach* loop construct, where it iterates over a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting gotcha with the for-range idiom: it is not a C for loop. The loop will run n times with the values k=0 to n-1, regardless of how k is modified in the loop body. If you want to simulate a C-style for loop (where you can terminate early by changing the loop variable), use a while loop instead.